# set default audio input device as audio output

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio

I'm on mint cinnamon 64bit.
I need to set the default audio input device to the audio output.
I know pulse audio can set the input for an application. but that works only when you can record and access pulse audio at the same time. 
In my case, I'm trying to record the audio with telegram. so I can't leave the telegram interface while recording. and when I'm not recording it isn't in the record tab of pulse audio.
So I need to set the actual default device or find a way to make telegram record output as input permanently.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not really clear what you are trying to do. ["Telegram Desktop"](https://telegram.org/) is a messaging and SMS App, also available on Linux for the Desktop, so I'm not entirely sure how you would record sound with it. If it's a normal Pulseaudio application, you can choose the audio input device ("source") with `pavucontrol`, and that association should be restored the next time you start it. If you want to create a loopback from an audio input device (source) to an audio output device (sink) instead, please say so.

Comment: @dirkt telegram has a record button that records audio as ogg and sends it. but it records only when you hold left click on the button. so it becomes complicated if I waned to work with `pavucontrol`at the same time.

Comment: Ideas: (1) Set default sink with `pacmd set-default-source`, then start telegram, hope it doesn't already have source associated with it and uses the default one. (2) If that doesn't work, and if you have a second device you can use to login remotely with `ssh`:  You can switch the source from the commandline with `pacmd` (I can write an answer for details). So use one hand to hold mouse button, one hand to type. (3) File a bug report with telegram. It makes sense to only record while doing an action for safety reasons, but it's still a problem.

Comment: @dirkt thank you. your first idea worked perfectly. can you write it in more detail as an answer for others having the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Find name of Pulseaudio sources from the commandline:

```
$ pacmd list-sources | grep name:
```

This list the name in `<angular brackets>`, use the name without brackets for other `pacmd` calls.

2) Set the default source:

```
$ pacmd set-default-source name_of_source
```

A Pulseaudio application will choose the default source on startup, unless there's already an association with another source.

3) Move an existing audio stream from the commandline to a different source, e.g. while logged in from a second device via `ssh` so the mouse can be pressed at the same time. First find the index of the existing source outputs:

```
$ pacmd list-source-outputs | egrep '(index)|(name)'
```

Pick the one for your application (terminal), then

```
$ pacmd move-source-output index_of_output name_of_new_sink
```

This should create an association between application and source that will be restored when the application is started next time.